# Confusion in resultant velocity and relative velocity?

Tags: vectors

A train is moving towards east and a car is along north, both with same speed. The observed direction of car to the passenger in the train is.

I drew the diagram like this (blue one)and got answer as north east or east north direction.

[image]

My questions are

It is normal right if relative velocity and resultant velocity have same direction and drawn like this.

(This is the red diagram ).Also , I saw online that they drew velocity of train towards left without even making it$ -V_t$. I didn’t understand why they did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Resultant vector* is the *sum* of two vectors in the parallelogram diagram.

*Difference* vector is the *relative vector*.

Note that there are two possibilities of relative vector depending on the sense of the vectors considered. Shown as $A-B$ and $B-A$ in the diagram. The relative vector is obtained by changing the sense (direction) of one of the given vectors and then finding the resultant, found in the arrow tip to head placed the usual way.

[image]